# How to make bar graph of 2 variables based on same DataFrame and I want to choose 2 or until 5 data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a DataFrame:

```
wilayah   branch   Income Januari 2018    Income Januari 2019    Income Febuari 2018     Income Febuari 2019     Income Jan-Feb 2018     Income Jan-Feb 2019
   1     sunarto   1000                     1500                     2000                     3000                     3333                     4431                    
   1     pemabuk   500                       700                     3000                     3000                     4333                     5431                    
   1     pemalas   2000                     2200                     4000                     3000                     5333                     6431                   
   1     hasuntato 9000                     1200                     6000                     3000                     2222                     2121                     
   1     sibodoh   1000                     1500                     3434                     3000                     2233                     2121                     
...
```

My expectation to to create a bar graph where x axis is every name in branch (e.g sunarto, pemabuk, pemalas, etc), and y axis is income.

Let's say I will compare sunarto's **income januari 2018** and **income januari 2019**, pemabuk's **income januari 2018** and **income januari 2019**, and so on (1 name in x axis, 2 values as comparison of two values). Then I will sort values high to low value from **Income Jan-Feb 2019** in my bar graph.

I tried:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = df1[["Sunarto","Income Januari 2018", "Income Januari 2019"]].plot(x='branch', kind='bar', color=["g","b"],rot=45)
plt.show()
```

Comment: You were close, use `df1[["branch", "Income Januari 2018", ....`, `"Sunarto"` is not a column of your DataFrame. Seems like this is a simple typo.

Comment: @ALollz thanks for your advise but, its not crucial

Comment: No, it really is. when you use `df[my_list]` you are subsetting your DataFrame to the column names contained in `my_list`. You are using the column `'Sunarto'`, but **that is not a column** in your DataFrame, it's an element of the column `'branch'`. I guarantee you are receiving a `KeyError`, which is solved by correctly replacing `'Sunarto'` with  `'branch'` column.

Comment: Stupid me, thanks @ALollz i will edit this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a `groupby` aggregation then run `DataFrame.plot`. Below will line all branches on x-axis with different income columns as color_coded keys in legend.

```
agg_df = df.groupby('branch').sum()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,5)) 

agg_df.plot(kind='bar', edgecolor='w', ax=ax, rot=22, width=0.5, fontsize = 15)

# ADD TITLES AND LABELS 
plt.title('Income by Branches, Jan/Feb 2018-2019', weight='bold', size=24) 
plt.xlabel('Branch', weight='bold', size=24) 
plt.ylabel('Income', weight='bold', size=20) 

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show() 
plt.clf()
```

Should you want each separate branch plots on specific columns, iterate off a `groupby` list:

```
dfs = df.groupby('branch')

for i,g in dfs:
   ord_cols = (pd.melt(g.drop(columns="wilayah"), id_vars = "branch")
                            .sort_values("value")["variable"].values
              )

   fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,4)) 

   (g.reindex(columns=ord_cols)
     .plot(kind='bar', edgecolor='w', ax=ax, rot=0, width=0.5, fontsize = 15)
   )

   # ADD TITLES AND LABELS 
   plt.title('Income by {} Branch, Jan/Feb 2018-2019'.format(i), 
             weight='bold', size=16) 
   plt.xlabel('Branch', weight='bold', size=16) 
   plt.ylabel('Income', weight='bold', size=14) 

   plt.tight_layout()
   plt.show()
```

[image: Groupby Plot Outputs]

Comment: can I sort values high to low value based on Income Jan-Feb 2019 in my bar graph?

Comment: sir, i can't run this code    
    for i,g in dfs:
       
       fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,5)) 
    
       (g.reindex(columns=["Income Januari 2018", "Income Januari 2019"])
the system said

ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-9-abe127e3b6b1> in <module>

     37 dfs = df2.groupby('Cabang').sum()

     38 

**---> 39 for i,g in dfs:**

     40 

     41    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,5))


ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: can i add the value for every bar?

Comment: Whoops! The list version should not have a `sum` on `groupby`. Also, I add an *ord_cols* list to sort bars in graphs. Be careful with this because colors and labels will change for each branch and not exactly comparable.